# Create a new 32bit value from an existing register value in mips

Tags: mips, mips32

I am new to mips.  I have the following instruction:

```
addi $s3, $0, '\n'
```

$s3 is now equal to 0x0000000a

Now I want to set $s4 to be 0x1001000a

I am trying this:

```
lui     $s4, 0x1001
ori     $s4, $s4, $s3
```

But I am getting an error on the ori statement.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` in `ori` means "immediate" - this form of the instruction expects an immediate (literal constant) for the third argument.

In your case you have a register for the third argument, so you just want `or`:

```
lui     $s4, 0x1001
or      $s4, $s4, $s3
```

See [this handy MIPS instruction set reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).

Comment: Awesome!  That was it.  Thank you much appreciated.